# Running a custom command (Courgette tests) on AWS device farm

Tags: aws-device-farm, courgette

From the documentation it seems that rather than running or specifying a command to run the tests, you zip up the test files and upload them. I haven't tried this but I can't work out how it would know to run Courgette with `npx courgette`.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-test-run.html

Followed this:
Step 5: Upload Your Custom Test Spec (Optional)

but grabbed the APPIUM_NODE_TEST_SPEC one instead of the JAVA one they use in the example.